# Query Function not working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am having a lot of trouble with this. I found the problem but don't know how to solve it.
This is my query function in Google Sheets. The error it is giving me is:
"Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC"

I realized that this is happening because the values in Column Q are actually another function.

For example, Visibly one cell in column Q is "$1,338.1424" but if you click on the cell the actual contents are "=IF(ISBLANK(R12)," ",R12*L12)" I can't figure out a way to make the query function sum the values in Column Q in light of this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have not been able to find anything to help.

```html
=query(Trades_April,"SELECT SUM(Q) WHERE W Contains 'PS'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the cell has a formula in it but that the value "$1,338.1424" is not numeric, it is text.

Solution: Try to change the formula in the cell to this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(R12)," ",VALUE(R12*L12)
```

Another possibility may be: selecting the column Q and changing the format to "Number".

If these did not work, please post a link to a version of your spreadsheet (without sensitive data) and I will try to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work until I wrapped the entire function in the value function like this:
=iferror(ifna(value(IF(ISBLANK(R12)," ",R12*L12))))

Comment: I’m glad that I could at least give you an idea :) If your question has been resolved, please mark the thread as answered.